# Changing working precision to 10 in `NIntegrate` introducing error messages and giving bigger error than precision 5

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I have two numerical integrals as follows:

```
u[t_, p_] := Cos[t/2]*Exp[I*p/2];
v[t_, p_] := Sin[t/2]*Exp[-I*p/2];
r[t1_, p1_, t2_, p2_] := 2*Abs[u[t1, p2]*v[t2, p2] - u[t2, p2]*v[t1, p1]];

intk2[k_, twoS_, L_, wp_] := 
  NIntegrate[(r[t1, p1, t2, p2]/2)^(2*twoS - 2*L + k)*(2*
       Sqrt[twoS/2])^k*Abs[u[t1, p1]]^(2*L)*Abs[u[t2, p2]]^(2*L)*
    Exp[-Sqrt[twoS/2]*r[t1, p1, t2, p2]]*Sin[t1]*Sin[t2], {t1, 0, 
    Pi}, {t2, 0, Pi}, {p1, 0, 2*Pi}, {p2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> wp];

norm[twoS_, L_, wp_] := 
  NIntegrate[(r[t1, p1, t2, p2]/2)^(2*twoS - 2*L)*
    Abs[u[t1, p1]]^(2*L)*Abs[u[t2, p2]]^(2*L)*Sin[t1]*Sin[t2], {t1, 0,
     Pi}, {t2, 0, Pi}, {p1, 0, 2*Pi}, {p2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> wp];
```

I need this for a set of parameters, and when I run for example `Table[intk2[i, 9, j, 5], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]` and `Table[norm[9, j, 5], {j, 0, 5}]`, with working precision 5, there is no problem. However I can check the accuracy against the exact answer (a long story involving several other functions, see below), and would like it to be better.

So I try to use better working precision and run `Table[intk2[i, 9, j, 10], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}]` and `Table[norm[9, j, 10], {j, 0, 5}]`. This time however I get error messages like 
`Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.`

Also I can check that the accuracy is lower than before.

This seems counter intuitive. How can better working precision give worse answers?

.

.

Here's how I can check the answers:

I define

```
i96 = Table[intk2[i, 9, j, 10], {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}];
n = Table[norm[9, j, 10], {j, 0, 5}];
```

and

```
VLLL[twoS_, J_] := 
  2*Binomial[2*twoS - 2*J, twoS - J]*
   Binomial[2*twoS + 2*J + 2, 
     twoS + J + 1]/(Sqrt[twoS/2]*Binomial[2*twoS + 2, twoS + 1]^2);
V[l_, L_, twoS_] := 
  Sum[(-1)^(twoS + L)*(2*l + 1)^2*SixJSymbol[{L, l, l}, {k, l, l}]*
     ThreeJSymbol[{l, -twoS/2}, {k, 0}, {l, twoS/2}]^2, {k, 0, 2*l}]/
   Sqrt[twoS/2];
```

and solve the simultaneous equations

```
Solve[{VLLL[9, 
     0] + (C0*i96[[1, 1]] + C1*i96[[2, 1]] + C2*i96[[3, 1]] + 
       C3*i96[[4, 1]] + C4*i96[[5, 1]] + C5*i96[[6, 1]])/n[[1]] == 
   V[5.5, 0, 9], 
  VLLL[9, 1] + (C0*i96[[1, 2]] + C1*i96[[2, 2]] + C2*i96[[3, 2]] + 
       C3*i96[[4, 2]] + C4*i96[[5, 2]] + C5*i96[[6, 2]])/n[[2]] == 
   V[5.5, 1, 9], 
  VLLL[9, 2] + (C0*i96[[1, 3]] + C1*i96[[2, 3]] + C2*i96[[3, 3]] + 
       C3*i96[[4, 3]] + C4*i96[[5, 3]] + C5*i96[[6, 3]])/n[[3]] == 
   V[5.5, 2, 9], 
  VLLL[9, 3] + (C0*i96[[1, 4]] + C1*i96[[2, 4]] + C2*i96[[3, 4]] + 
       C3*i96[[4, 4]] + C4*i96[[5, 4]] + C5*i96[[6, 4]])/n[[4]] == 
   V[5.5, 3, 9], 
  VLLL[9, 4] + (C0*i96[[1, 5]] + C1*i96[[2, 5]] + C2*i96[[3, 5]] + 
       C3*i96[[4, 5]] + C4*i96[[5, 5]] + C5*i96[[6, 5]])/n[[5]] == 
   V[5.5, 4, 9], 
  VLLL[9, 5] + (C0*i96[[1, 6]] + C1*i96[[2, 6]] + C2*i96[[3, 6]] + 
       C3*i96[[4, 6]] + C4*i96[[5, 6]] + C5*i96[[6, 6]])/n[[6]] == 
   V[5.5, 5, 9]}, {C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5}]
```

I then define the answer {C1,...,C5} as `c2` and make the function

```
ppVeff2[twoS_, L_, c_, K_, wp_] := 
  NIntegrate[((r[t1, p1, t2, p2]/2)^(2*twoS - 2*L - 1)*(2*
           Sqrt[twoS/2])^(-1) + 
       Sum[c[[k + 
           1]]*(r[t1, p1, t2, p2]/2)^(2*twoS - 2*L + k)*(2*
            Sqrt[twoS/2])^k*Exp[-Sqrt[twoS/2]*r[t1, p1, t2, p2]], {k, 
         0, K - 1}])*Abs[u[t1, p1]]^(2*L)*Abs[u[t2, p2]]^(2*L)*
     Sin[t1]*Sin[t2], {t1, 0, Pi}, {t2, 0, Pi}, {p1, 0, 2*Pi}, {p2, 0,
      2*Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> wp]/n[[L + 1]];
```

Finally I run `ppVeff2[9, 0, c2, 6, 5]`, where I know the answer should be `0.270607`. Using the answers with Working precision 10 I find `0.29043`, while precision 5 gives `0.27696`.

Increasing the number of coefficients in `c2={C1,...}` would also make this answer better, but I'd like to get as good accuracy as possible from the numerical integration as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the option `Method -> {"Multidimensional", "Generators" -> 9}` takes care of most of the cases, at least as far as the warning messages go.  There were a few exceptions, which suggests that intervention on a case by case basis may be necessary if further investigations are needed.

```
gen[2, 3] = 5;
gen[4, 0] = 6;
gen[4, 4] = 5;
gen[5, 0] = 5;
gen[5, 1] = 5;
gen[5, 3] = 5;
gen[5, 4] = 5;
gen[__] = 9;

intk2[k_, twoS_, L_, wp_] := 
  NIntegrate[(r[t1, p1, t2, p2]/2)^(2*twoS - 2*L + k)*(2*
       Sqrt[twoS/2])^k*Abs[u[t1, p1]]^(2*L)*Abs[u[t2, p2]]^(2*L)*
    Exp[-Sqrt[twoS/2]*r[t1, p1, t2, p2]]*Sin[t1]*Sin[t2], 
   {t1, 0, Pi}, {t2, 0, Pi}, {p1, 0, 2*Pi}, {p2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> wp,
   Method -> {"Multidimensional", "Generators" -> gen[k, L]}];

norm[twoS_, L_, wp_] := 
  NIntegrate[(r[t1, p1, t2, p2]/2)^(2*twoS - 2*L)*
      Abs[u[t1, p1]]^(2*L)*Abs[u[t2, p2]]^(2*L)*Sin[t1]*Sin[t2],
   {t1, 0, Pi}, {t2, 0, Pi}, {p1, 0, 2*Pi}, {p2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> wp,
   Method -> {"Multidimensional", "Generators" -> If[L == 0, 6, 9]}];
```

The value returned by `ppVeff2[9, 0, c2, 6, 10]` is `0.2769071357`, a very modest improvement over a working precision of `5`.

As to what's going on numerically, the computation is so slow, it discourages tracking down precisely what's going on.  High dimensional integrals are particularly hard to evaluate, and four-dimensional ones are hard to visualize.  But generally, errors sometimes cancel each other out, sometimes not.  A change in the working precision causes a change in the precision goal, which leads to changes in the criteria for convergence as well as in sampling.  That it happens once, that a precision of 5 gives a better result than a precision of 10, is not that surprising to me.